# Google Fusion Tables - Event to close infoWindowHtml

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

Currently using `infoWindowHtml` to populate the tooltip within an Ajax request.  Though, I would like to just remove the thing on an event if possible, that would be fantastic.  Any Ideas?

Or do I have to do `infowindow.setContent()` and then `.open`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your own info windows, which allow you control over when they're opened, where they display, what the content is, and when they close. Here are the basic steps:

- The click event on the layer gives you the lat/lon coordinate of the event - use this to position the info window.
- Use infoWindowHtml from the event to set the content.
- Use the open method of the info window the show the window on the map.
- Finally, use the close method to hide the info window on any event.

Here's a link to the info window reference for more information:

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#InfoWindow

Comment: Hey Kathryn, got another quick question:

    if (event) { 
     infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      'content' : event.infoWindowHtml = "some html",
      'position' : event.latLng
     });
     infowindow.open();

It adds the object with the close method to the infowindow var, though with the infoWindowHtml, it pops it up automatically and I don't have control over it any longer. If i remove infoWindowHtml and call open(), it just loads the default fusion table data. Mind you, this is within an non-async ajax request. Thanks again!

Comment: Wes, You should take the time to clearly explain your problem and perhaps post some code or a link to your page.  I cannot decipher what you question/problem is.

Comment: Yes, I think posting more of the code would be helpful. Two things to look into in the meantime: (1) Make sure you're suppressing the layer info windows by setting the suppressInfoWindow field to true. (2) The content of the new InfoWindow object you're creating should be set as follows: content:event.infoWindowHtml. Remove the = "some html".

Comment: I got it figured out Kathryn, thanks again! It was a facepalm moment, appreciate the patience, you're doing an excellent job with fusion tables!